# Is it possible to construct symbols in SymPy that anticommute?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, commutativity

I need to implement some Grassmann variables in python (i.e. anti-commuting variables). In other words, I would like something with behavior as follows

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y = symbols('x y')
>>> y*x
-x*y
>>> y*y
0
```

One other feature I would need from this is the ability to give a canonical ordering to my variables. When I typed `>>> y*x`, it would certainly have been valid to also output `y*x` over `-x*y`. But, I would like the ability to choose that `x` should appear to the left of `y` (perhaps only after calling a function `simplify(y*x)`).

Does SymPy or some other library have this ability? If not, what would be the best way to go about implementing this myself (e.g. should I create a symbolic library myself, extend SymPy, etc.)?

Comment: I think this is what you want http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/anticommutator.html

Comment: Thank you! That looks very promising. I will investigate it now.

Comment: it's the closest I know from what you asked... and from what I remember from the source code it's rather readable.. so you might be able to expand it if needed.

Comment: You can use matrices of symbols to accomplish that. Using tensor product of Pauli matrices, for a suitable linear combination you can obtain objects that does anti-commute under the matrix product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new class inheriting from `Symbol` and change its behaviour on multiplication (`__mul__`) to the desired one.
To make this any useful, you need a canonic ordering anyway, which should be the same as SymPy’s (which at a quick glance appears to be by name, i.e., `Symbol.name`) to avoid problems.

```
from sympy import Symbol, S

class AnticomSym(Symbol):
    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs,commutative=False)

    def __mul__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other,AnticomSym):
            if other==self:
                return S.Zero
            elif other.name<self.name:
                return -Symbol.__mul__(other,self)

        return super().__mul__(other)

    def __pow__(self,exponent):
        if exponent>=2:
            return S.Zero
        else:
            return super().__pow__(exponent)


x = AnticomSym("x")
y = AnticomSym("y")

assert y*x == -x*y
assert y*y == 0
assert y**2 == 0
assert y**1 == y
assert ((x+y)**2).expand() == 0
assert x*y-y*x == 2*x*y
```

Now, this still does not resolve complex products such as `x*y*x*y` correctly.
For this, we can write a function that sorts an arbitrary product (using bubble sort):

```
from sympy import Mul

def sort_product(product):
    while True:
        if not isinstance(product,Mul):
            return product

        arglist = list(product.args)
        i = 0
        while i < len(arglist)-1:
            slice_prod = arglist[i]*arglist[i+1]
            is_mul = isinstance(slice_prod,Mul)
            arglist[i:i+2] = slice_prod.args if is_mul else [slice_prod]
            i += 1

        new_product = Mul(*arglist)
        if product == new_product:
            return new_product
        product = new_product

z = AnticomSym("z")
assert sort_product(y*(-x)) == x*y
assert sort_product(x*y*x*y) == 0
assert sort_product(z*y*x) == -x*y*z
```

Finally, we can write a function that sorts all products within an expression by iterating through the expression tree and applying `sort_product` to every product it encounters:

```
def sort_products(expr):
    if expr.is_Atom:
        return expr
    else:
        simplified_args = (sort_products(arg) for arg in expr.args)
        if isinstance(expr,Mul):
            return sort_product(Mul(*simplified_args))
        else:
            return expr.func(*simplified_args)

from sympy import exp
assert sort_products(exp(y*(-x))) == exp(x*y)
assert sort_products(exp(x*y*x*y)-exp(z*y*z*x)) == 0
assert sort_products(exp(z*y*x)) == exp(-x*y*z)
```

Note that I may still not have accounted for every eventuality.

Comment: I was just looking into doing something like this. Great answer!

Comment: I am running into an issue with expressions like `>>> c*b*a`. The output I would like is `-a*b*c`, but instead I get `-b*c*a`. I believe this is because `a*b` returns `-Mul(b,a)`. So, I believe I also need to override class Mul. If you have any suggestions for how best to go about this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This essentially is the reason why `x*y*x*y` does not resolve correctly.

Comment: Although, I'm wondering now, if it might be simpler to just create Symbols that are non-commutative. Then, construct a function that takes a product of these symbols, which orders these symbols appropriately (getting the right overall sign and evaluating to zero if any symbol appears more than once).

Comment: Anyway, any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Wrzlprmft's answer is a great start so I will add the next logical step. Since you are asking for anticommuting symbols to be handled by a computer algebra system, it is reasonable to assume that you want to be able to differentiate with respect to them. This will require a function to overwrite sympy's product rule.

```
from sympy import Add, Mul, prod
from sympy.ntheory.multinomial import multinomial_coefficients_iterator

def AnticomDeriv(ptr, s, n):
    args = ptr.args
    m = len(args)
    terms = []
    factor = S.One
    if isinstance(s, AnticomSym):
        if n > 1:
            return S.Zero
        args = list(args)
        for i in range(len(args)):
            d = args[i].diff(s)
            terms.append(factor * reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, (args[:i] + [d] + args[i + 1:]), S.One))
            if isinstance(args[i], AnticomSym):
                factor *= -1
        return Add.fromiter(terms)
    for kvals, c in multinomial_coefficients_iterator(m, n):
        p = prod([arg.diff((s, k)) for k, arg in zip(kvals, args)])
        terms.append(c * p)
    return Add(*terms)

Mul._eval_derivative_n_times = AnticomDeriv
```

This will give the following (correct) behaviour.

```
>>> x = AnticomSym('x')
>>> y = AnticomSym('y')
>>> expr = x*y
>>> expr.diff(x)
y
>>> expr.diff(y)
-x
```